# Remap function keys on magic keyboard

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, keyboard

I have an old magic keyboard that still works. I'm using it connected to my m1 16-inch macbook pro. However, F5 and F6 on the macbook pro keyboard is defined as Diction and "Do Not Disturb", while it is blank on the magic keyboard. How can I modify the behavior of these function keys on the magic keyboard so that it resembles that of the internal keyboard?

Answer (score 0):

[Karabiner Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org) is perfect for this. In the **Function keys** tab, you can remap individual function keys to any other key.

Comment: Does it recognize the two different keyboards and treat them accordingly?